# Runnable ,Handler, Thread

Tags: android

I was making a stopwatch app and I went through the code

```
 private void runtime(){

        final Handler handler = new Handler();
        handler.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                final TextView timeView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
                int hours = sec/3600;
                int min = sec/60;
                int secs = sec%60;
                String time = String.format("%d:%02d:%02d",hours,min,secs);
                timeView.setText(time);
                if(running){
                    sec++;
                }
                handler.postDelayed(this,1000);
            }
        });
```

I don't know anything about runnable, handler and thread can you please describe these terms
and why they are used

Comment: Please do not ask questions like this in here

Comment: You can check out this. https://developer.android.com/training/multiple-threads/communicate-ui#java

Comment: go through documentation first to get to know what is what and basic stuff then ask your question, also handler with empty constructor is deprecated use it with looper in it `Handler h = new Handler(Looper.getLooper());`

Comment: also check out Timer, work manager and Coroutines

Answer (score 0):

Refer android documentation to get a clear idea,

What's happening here is you are creating a 'Handler' to run a code which is in the 'Runnable' which contains a `postDelayed()` method to repeat the same code every 1 second till you dismiss that runnable

In general, a handler is used to execute a block of code in a 'Single Thread', the block of code which is executed with the Thread's message queue is the 'Runnable', Runnable Interface has a `run()` method which holds your code

`postDelayed()` method is one of the methods in Handler class which we use for Scheduling Messages or for Scheduled Execution of any code, in this case, it is to run the above code for every 1 second.

For more info refer this [link](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler)